# How to include a modal button in the header of WP site?

Tags: wordpress, modal-dialog, typeform

I have a Wordpress site and I am trying  to add a button to the header which opens a modal/popup to a Typeform form.

I am able to achieve this button in the body of the site, however when I try to put this button in the header, instead of opening as a modal it redirects to  the actual website.

Do you have any thoughts on how to implement a modal that is triggered by a button in the header? I would like to avoid using plug-ins, however if that is the best solution I am open to it.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

I believe you could use Typeform [Embed SDK](https://developer.typeform.com/embed/) to achieve what you want.

Step 1: create a button and add it to the header of your site.

Step 2: Give this button a unique id

Step 3: Add this piece of code that will create a modal/popup when the button is clicked

```
const reference = typeformEmbed.makePopup(
  'YOUR_TYPEFORM_URL', // NOTE: Replace with your typeform URL
  {
    mode: 'popup',
    autoClose: 3000,
    hideHeaders: true,
    hideFooters: true,
    onSubmit: function () {
      console.log('Typeform successfully submitted')
    }
  }
)

document.getElementById("YOUR_BUTTON_ID").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    reference.open()
})
```

Hope it helps :)